# Regex parenthesis

Tags: regex

I problem in Regex, the URL no with match:

```
Sound/ranzor%20S001/sound,ranzor%20S001,245--40%20ZR20%20(95Y),TL,AMR
```

Expression of Regex is:

```
((.+?)/(.+?)/.+?,.+?,(\d+)--(\d{1,3})%\d{2}R(\d{1,3})%\d{2}|(\d{1,3}\w).*)
```

The problem is **(95Y)**.

Thanks.

**The solution:**

```
((.+?)/(.+?)/.+?,.+?,(\d+)--(\d{1,})%\d{2}.?.?(\d{1,})%\d{2}\((\d{1,})(\w{1}).*)
```

The solution is escape **"("**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this regex:

`/((.+?)/(.+?)/.+?,.+?,(\d+)--(\d{1,3})\%\d{2}R(\d{1,3})\%\d{2}|\(\d{1,3}\w\).*)/`

You need to escape `%`, `(` and `)`.
To do so, add backslash before them

Answer (score 2):

In the middle `R` should be changed to `ZR`. Also I don't understand why you used the OR (`|`) Pattern, I removed it, and put parentheses around:

```
(.+?)/(.+?)/.+?,.+?,(\d+)--(\d{1,3})%\d{2}ZR(\d{1,3})%\d{2}\((\d{1,3}\w)\).*
```

Comment: that was another problem. Thanks.