# How to match text or numbers inside parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, match

I am looking for a formula that matches with numbers and parenthesis.

```
"Please answer your name of bank.(1) (bank of america)"
```

For `(1)` I used `\d([1])`
For `(bank of america)` I came up with `\*([a-b])`

Comment: Regex in reverse polish notation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900397/regex-parenthesis)

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `(` and `)` characters here. The regex is:

```
\(1\) \([^)]+\)
```

Sample test using Python:

```
s = "Please answer your name of bank.(1) (bank of america)"
print re.findall('\(1\) \([^)]+\)', s)
```

Output:

```
['(1) (bank of america)']
```